# Class member variable that takes the class as a template

Tags: c++, templates

So, in a recent C++ project, I've implemented a packet factory-like system where each new packet class automatically registers itself using a static register. One of the packet types is as follows:

```
class Packet0Connect : public Packet{
public:
    Packet0Connect();
    Packet0Connect(const std::string& name, const std::string& info);
    virtual void write(std::ostream& os) const;
    virtual void read(std::istream& is);
    virtual Packet* clone() const;
    std::string name, info;
private:
    static const PacketRegister<Packet0Connect> registry;
};
```

Here is what PacketRegister looks like:

```
template<class P>
class PacketRegister{
public:
    PacketRegister(){
        PacketMap* packetMap = PacketManager::getPacketMap();
        if(packetMap->count(prototype.packetID) == 0){
            packetMap->insert(std::make_pair(prototype.packetID, (const Packet*)&prototype));
        }
    }
    P prototype;
};
```

The registry variable is properly initialized at the top of an implementation file, and in its constructor it adds a mapping to the specific packet type, in this case Packet0Connect, with its ID. I quite like that way I managed to do this, as it doesn't allocate any memory on the stack. The above compiles fine using GCC 4.2.1 on Mac OSX, however, when I tried to compile with Visual C++ 2010 on 32-bit Windows Vista, I run into this error:

```
error C2079: 'PacketRegister<P>::prototype' uses undefined class 'Packet0Connect'
    with
    [
        P=Packet0Connect
    ]
    see reference to class template initialization 'PacketRegister<P>' being compiled
    with
    [
        P=Packet0Connect
    ]
```

After doing some googling about the error, I found out that it usually gets thrown when you try to use a forward declared class as a template argument. That does make sense, because Packet0Connect isn't fully defined when the PacketRegister is, but there must be a way to make this work with VC++. I know I could just make the register a global variable after defining the class, but I would prefer not to if I can make it work as a static member variable.

Comment: You might be able to make `P prototype` a local variable of `PacketRegister::PacketRegister()`. Not sure if that alone helps, but if it doesn’t, you could then move the definition of `PacketRegister::PacketRegister()` out of line and only include it after the declaration of `Packet0Connect`

Comment: That might work, but then the varaible would go out of scope when the constructor returns, making the map pointer invalid.

Comment: Ah yes, my browser window was not wide enough to see that you were taking that address. BTW, is there any reason you cannot use standard C++ RTTI mechanisms in lieu of `prototype`?

Comment: How would you suggest I use RTTI in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the compiler can't determine size of `Packet0Connect`. Change type of `Packet0Connect::registry` from `PacketRegister<Packet0Connect>` to `PacketRegister<Packet0Connect> *`.

Comment: Then I would have to initialize the pointer with `new`, and I would prefer to keep things off the stack, not that it makes a huge difference with the variable being static.

Comment: @Jsnman Note that a Packet0Connect contains a PacketRegister<Packet0Connect>, and a PacketRegister<Packet0Connect> contains a Packet0Connect. Do you really want infinite recursion in stack?

Comment: I thought I would avoid that because PacketRegister<Packet0Connect> is static. Wouldn't that mean there's no recursion?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe each of PacketRegister and Packet0Connect is dependent to the other and you did not declare Packet0Connect before PacketRegister. No problem with the given code only. Check the dependencies and you might be forward-declare it.